# Pasar una cadena a una funcion y modifcarla. En C

Tags: c

Hola tengo un problema que resolver.
Yo tengo un array de esta forma p[] = "jorge,50,2000". Lo que hice fue separar cada vez que aparezca una "," y guardarlo en otro array, quedando como resultado "Jorge","50","2000".
Bueno lo que yo quiero y no puedo hacer es tomar un elemento del array por ejemplo "Jorge" y pasarlo como parametro a otra función, modificarlo y devolver el valor modificado a array.
por ejemplo agarro a "Jorge" y lo modifico a "Mariano" y el array tendria que quedar "Mariano","50","2000".

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>



void pasarcadena(char const *cadena1);


int main ()
{
    char buf[] ="Jorge,Gimenez,505,50,2,4";
    int i = 0;
    char *p = strtok (buf, ",");
    char *array[6];

    while (p != NULL)
    {
        array[i++] = p;
        p = strtok (NULL, ",");
    }
   char * nombre = array[0];

   for (i = 0; i < 6; ++i) 
        printf("%s\n", array[i]);


    pasarcadena(nombre);
    printf("el valor ya modificado es %s\n",nombre);
    return 0;
}
void pasarcadena(char const * cadena1)
{
//Acá no se como poder hacerlo
}
```

Comment: Usa la función `strncpy`: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstring/strncpy/

Answer (score 1):

deberias sacar const y usar la funcion strcpy:

```
void pasarcadena(char * cadena1)
{
    char nom[] = "Mariano";
    strcpy(cadena1,nom);
}
```

o tambien podes simplificar:

```
void pasarcadena(char * cadena1)
{
    strcpy(cadena1,"Mariano");
}
```